# Dead GRUB after upgrade on server 18.04

Tags: boot, server, grub2

Per title, GRUB has suddenly gone dead.

Normal boot gets the menu, but any selection goes to blank screen, no HDD activity.

Editing ('e' key) making any changes, and hitting F10 goes to blank screen, no HDD activity.

Commandline ('c') gets the usual grub> prompt, it does a "set pager=1" and returns to grub> prompt.

Typing "ls" freezes GRUB, no HDD activity.

[image]

Is this the point to format the server, lose everything on it, because GRUB is suddenly unable to find any partitions? Or, should I dare try installing GRUB2 from UBCD to try to force a manual boot, just to get into the system?

Note: UBCD/Parted Magic finds all of them, browses all of them, but I have no idea where the actual GRUB is, since the config for is a result of the update-grub (which succeeded).

Note also; This mess is the direct result of a seemingly innocent answer for the netplan issue on Ubuntu server (netplan problem is a whole different thing), where the suggested fix for missing eth0 was:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0"
```

Added to GRUB config and a grub-update, promptly thereafter on the reboot, GRUB is bricked.

Comment: Even though the Ultimate Boot CD (UBCD) seems a good idea, I'd stick with an Ubuntu distro and boot the 18.04 live CD, choose try Ubuntu and install [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). It will figure out if GRUB2 is a good idea for you and try to repair the GRUB that you have. Upload the log to the pastebin server and update your question with the URL to the pastebin log.

Comment: So, which option is that, on the Ubuntu Server Live image?
There's never been a "Try" option for server, iirc... Desktop Live CD won't load the server partitions beyond asking where to install.. No logs to show, still can't boot into the server. I'll edit a note: "Advanced Options" from the Server Live image is an empty menu, only "back".

Comment: AFter some digging, found there's a stand-along image of that boot-repair..
Ran it, No errors shown that I could tell. It reinstalled grub.. gave me the URL https://pastebin.com/P/V7vmGMBYVS/ which is a 404 error.. And machine is deader than before, no grub menu, no SHIFT menu, nada.

Format and reinstall Ubuntu LTS, losing all users, mail, etc.. This time I'l pay attention and remove netplan and reinstall ifupdown so everything works like it's supposed to.